# Changing the signs of the antidiagonal elements of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d
  \end{pmatrix}$$

such that $\operatorname{det}(A) \neq 0$. I would like to find two other non singular matrices such that

$$BAC=\begin{pmatrix}
    a & -b \\
    -c & d
  \end{pmatrix}$$

can this be done in general?

Answer (score 1):

Just take $\;B=C=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

As observed by @Andreas Caranti, this shows the two matrices are similar, not only equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is nonsingular, you can just take $C=A^{-1}$ and $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
    a & -b \\
    -c & d
  \end{pmatrix}$$

for example.